# Selector.select() does not fill selectedKeys() if wakeup() is called before select()

Tags: java, nio, wakeup

I have a somewhat complex loop processing several different NIO channels and other objects. Some of these objects trigger their processing (i.e. simulate a "select"-event) by calling ***[Selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html).[wakeup()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup())***.

When I accidentally put my thread into a busy-loop by always calling ***wakeup()*** before every call to ***[select()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select())***, I noticed that my other NIO channels were no longer getting serviced at all. As soon as the condition triggering the busy-loop went away, all other channels were immediately serviced again as usual.

After a bit of messing around with this I figured out that the reason for my other channels no longer being serviced was that ***select()*** did not fill the list of ***[selectedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectedKeys())*** if it returned immediately due to a pending ***wakeup()***.

Is this expected behavior? I couldn't find anything in the docs regarding this detail.
If so, is there a way to prevent this more elegantly than by following every ***select()*** with an additional ***[selectNow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectNow())***?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's expected. It retuned immediately because of the wakeup, so it didn't block looking for ready channels, populate the selected keys, etc.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I was assuming that wakeup(); select(); would be equivalent to selectNow();

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that wakeup(); selectNow(); then also doesn't populate the selected keys?